# Building application for Android accessibility mode for blind people

Tags: android, accessibility, voice

I would like to know how good is the TalkBack accessibility service provided by Android for blind people. Is it really usable to them? and how big is such a community of users?

I am intending to build an app to serve this type of users and I am not sure how to integrate it with the accessibility mode. What I see is that the TalkBack service is not that good. So, I want to make my app voice enabled. Will this contradict with the Android's Accessibility mode?

Answer (score 4):

I’m a totally blind software developer who uses an iPhone as their primary phone. I have played with Android 4.0 on a Novo 7 Paladin tablet. The experience was not very good and it was barely usable. From things I’ve read the accessibility of an Android device depends on the manufacturer since they are able to customize it. I’ve heard everything from an Android device being almost as accessible as an iPhone to completely unusable depending on the person and device. For more information you might want to read and post to the eyes-free android group which can be found at
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/eyes-free
While I don’t have numbers to back this up and it probably varies by market if you want to specifically target blind users I’d go for iOS instead. Both the iPhone and iPod touch appear to be popular devices among blind people. In addition to the devices being popular since Apple is the only one selling devices with iOS you can be pretty much guaranteed that accessibility will work the same across all devices. This is not the case for Android devices as mentioned above.

Comment: I am well aware of how advanced iOS is in this area. Yet I am aiming to target Android users. I agree with you that everything before Jelly Bean is barley usable for a blind user. I have tried several Samsung and HTC devices and the experience was crappy in all of them. Yet, Jelly Bean on Note 2 seemed pretty amazing to me. Jelly Bean currently is only 10% of the market against Gingerbread and ICS which are almost 80% of it. So targeting blind users of Jelly Bean or Android in general is a very long term investment. Thank you for your valuable feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I am from China, last month I join an exhibition and many companies showed their products. 
There was a company working on how to help Chinese blind people use smart phone(Android an Symbian).

They said there are 5 million blind people, only 20 thousands people using their product. But they are not expecting much blind people use their product because few blind people own their own smart phone.So they treat it as a public welfare instead of business.

I watched the demo, it was an application installed on your smart phone. With the application's help, the blind people could use many application. Very impressive.

I could post more information if you need it.

Comment: 20 thousand users is a quite impressive number. Sadly, I guess the number of blind people using smart phones where I live in the Middle East wouldn't go beyond a few thousands if not hundreds.

Comment: And btw, the accessibility mode in iPhone works greatly and there is a huge community of blind people that use it. The problem now is with the Android since their TalkBack is not very mature yet. That is why I want to know how people actually use it. There is a big opportunity for innovation in this field. Thank you for the valuable information.